# Custom Validator firing but it does not update the ValidationSummary

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, customvalidator, validationsummary

Hi I am working on a custom form field validator, it seems like the custom validator is working by not allowing it to continue to the next page, but it doesn't update the Validation Summary nor does it display the asterisk and the labels that i've made visable. I also have other validators like RequiredFieldValidator on the same field. My ValidationGroup is set, as is the Text and IsValid. I even wrote and set a dummy client side validation method in javascript as some workarounds suggests.

here is the validation summary code in asp.net

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidatorSummary" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Step2" />
```

here is the custom validator and the required field one

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="AddressVerification" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid address." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Step2" OnServerValidate="AddressVerification_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidatorDummy" Text="*" Enabled="true" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFValidatorHomeAddress" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter home address." Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Step2" ControlToValidate="txtHomeAddress"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

here is the custom validation method in the code behind

```
protected void AddressVerification_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
//lets just say it doesn't validate and sets the IsValid to false
lblUspsValidatorResHomeCity.Visible = true;
lblUspsValidatorResHomeState.Visible = true;
lblUspsValidatorResHomeZip.Visible = true;
e.IsValid = false;
}
```

please advise, thanks.

EDIT:
Answered - as bitxwise mentioned. the validation summary should be placed inside an update panel as well. Thanks!

Like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelValidationSummaryHome" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional"
runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="AddressHomeValidationSummary" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddressHomeValidationGroup"
        CssClass="errors" /> 
</ContentTemplate>
```

and then calling the update:

```
UpdatePanelValidationSummaryHome.Update();
```

Comment: most probably you are missing ValidationSummary in your button tag. (that code you have not posted).

Comment: and CausesValidation is true by default for button.

Comment: I believe I've answered your question(s) so I'd appreciate it if you would update your question to properly reflect the involvement of an UpdatePanel and perhaps credit my answer...

Comment: thanks a bunch, I updated the original post accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be missing `ControlToValidate` in your declaration of `CustomValidator`.

**EDIT**

If your CustomValidator aggregates multiple controls, then try this:

ASPX

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="AddressVerification" runat="server"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid address."
    OnServerValidate="AddressVerification_ServerValidate"
    Text="*"
    ValidationGroup="Step2" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddress" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtMyTextBox"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter an address"
    Text="*"
    ValidationGroup="Step2" />
...
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidatorSummary" runat="server"
    ValidationGroup="Step2" />
...
<asp:Button ID="btnCheckAddresses" runat="server"
    CausesValidation="true"
    Text="Check Addresses"
    ValidationGroup="Step2" />
```

CS

```
protected void AddressVerification_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
    args.IsValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMyTextBox.Text) && !txtMyTextBox.Text.Contains(' ');
}
```

Note that the validation group of the control invoking the post back has `CausesValidation="true"` and has the same `ValidationGroup` as the validators.

**EDIT 2**

If your postback control was in the `UpdatePanel` but the `ValidationSummary` was not, then the partial postback would not have refreshed the `ValidationSummary`. Once you removed the postback control from the `UpdatePanel`, I imagine it would then generate a full postback, which would refresh your `ValidationSummary`.

I don't know what else is in your `UpdatePanel`, but [many people report having issues with their validators being in `UpdatePanel`'s](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10060098/validation-is-not-working-in-update-panel.aspx).

Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx),

> When you use the ValidationSummary
>   control inside an UpdatePanel control,
>   make sure that the validator control
>   and the control it is associated with
>   are in the same panel. For more
>   information about using the
>   UpdatePanel control for partial-page
>   updates, see Partial-Page Rendering
>   Overview.

as well as this [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattgi/archive/2007/01/23/asp-net-ajax-validators.aspx).

Comment: I read that the ControlToValidate is not required for a CustomValidator. Also, my CustomValidator aggregates data from multiple TextBox Controls. Also note that this code works on a different page which is really messing with my head right now. ha, maybe I missed something.

Comment: That's correct. I didn't know you had more than one control to validate in your CustomValidator and have updated my answer to reflect that. I've tested the code in my post and it works for me.

Comment: I did that as well. The validation works, I can step into it. It's just that it doesn't update the ValidationSummary . It validates everything, just doesn't provide good UX if it doesn't update the summary about what's going wrong. The other validator does update the validation summary. I can set an update panel as a work around but there should be no reason why the summary or the labels doesn't update. ...maybe it has something to do with postback? It's driving me crazy because I know the code works, I know your code works. errrr

Comment: Try simplifying your code to be a bit more bare bones. Put the validation code onto its own page and ensure that it works with just your textboxes, validators, and postback control. Then start adding other elements onto the page and see what's breaking it. Did you see the note I wrote below the code?

Comment: I fixed it, apparently the code that was handed down to me had the Button control inside an Update Panel, I saw that there was no reason why it should be inside an update panel, and it wasn't being used or called in the code behind or anywhere else so I removed it. Voila, it works! Now another question arises, why does having a Button inside a Update Panel break everything.

Comment: Is the ValidationSummary in the UpdatePanel as well?

Comment: it was just the button that was in the update panel... yeah, I'll have to look into it further. weird. thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you check out my answer - EDIT 2 - you'll see why your ValidationSummary didn't update. The postback resulting from your button was partial to the UpdatePanel that contained it. Since the ValidationSummary was not in the UpdatePanel, it wouldn't refresh.

Comment: that makes sense, but why did RequiredFieldValidator update the ValidationSummary?

Comment: RequiredFieldValidator does not require a postback to update ValidationSummary. It's triggered prior to the postback and actually prevents postback if the validator deems the form invalid through translated javascript. Keep in mind that your CustomValidator is implementing a server validation rather than a client one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure every control (textbox, checkbox, etc) that is being validated, every RequiredValidator, CustomValidator and ValidationSummary has the same **ValidationGroup** value.

ie.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="The field is required"
ValidationGroup="myValGroup">*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Of course this will only work if all the controls are inside the same panel or parent control.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the validation summary was not showing because the submit button was in a separate update panel.

```
<Triggers>                        
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonSubmit" />
</Triggers>
```

Once I added the above code the summary appeared.