# The customer validator error won't show inside the validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have added a `CustomValidator` to my page that validates the input on the server side. 
The validation works OK and shows the error message on screen when it is invalid but if I change it to show inside the `validationsummary` the page sets to `isvalid=false` but the `validationsummary` never shows.

I also have other validators (`RegularExpression`, `RequiredField`) on screen which work fine until I change the view mode of the `CustomValidator`, at which point they don't show either.

I have tried all existing threads including this one(below) but it the suggestion is to use an update panel as a wrapper. The problem is that you can't include the controls within it so I don't know exactly how to test the suggestion:

[Why The error message for custom validator is not shown in message box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704601/why-the-error-message-for-custom-validator-is-not-shown-in-message-box)

This is the HTML code:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validProductCode" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtProductCode"
    OnServerValidate="ValidateProductCode"
    ErrorMessage="The product code entered is invalid"
    Display="None" 
    ValidationGroup="IWS"/>

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="True" ShowSummary="False" ValidationGroup="IWS" />
```

This is the C#

```
protected void ValidateProductCode(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString()))
        using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_ProductCodes_FillScreen", conn))
        {
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", ddlSiteId.SelectedValue);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txtProductCode.Text);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsOntext", 1);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            args.IsValid = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
    }
}
```

Comment: The other validators have ValidationGroup = "IWS"? Have you also set this ValidationGroup on the control (Button, LinkButton, etc,) that launch the validation?

Comment: Yes I have done that. I added tried with and without the group and the outcome was the same. As soon as I change the customvalidator to display=none it all stops.

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518798/validationsummary-doest-show-errors OR THIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308475/custom-validator-firing-but-it-does-not-update-the-validationsummary

Comment: @jbutler483 That is a completely different issue and different validators. That user is wondering why the message doesn't show but it was because the error message wasn't set.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811734/elegant-way-to-make-customvalidator-work-with-validationsummary-messagebox

Comment: @sr28 I tried the suggestion in there and still made no difference.

Comment: have you tried to use [Page.ModelState.AddModelError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: @fuchs777 No but in what context do I use it and what will it do?

Comment: @connersz - did you try the second answer by bdukes?

Comment: @sr28 Yes but it didn't work. I have never had such a problem with validation but it seems like an issue just trying to get the custom validator into the summary.

Comment: @connersz anything you add with that function should show up in the ValidationSummary, if you're not in the codebehind page you could try to use (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page) to access the page.

Comment: @fuchs777 Do you have an example because I'm struggling to picture it.

Comment: @connersz little bit much for a comment, but its quite simple [click here](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/WebFormsModelBindingExtensions/blob/master/samples/AspNet.WebForms.ModelBinding.Extensions.Samples/Account/Manage.aspx.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that message box from validation summary is shown only on client validation stage in and is called from `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit` function which is called from `Page_ClientValidate` function:

```
function Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup) {
    Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
    if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], validationGroup, null);
    }
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
    ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);
    Page_BlockSubmit = !Page_IsValid;
    return Page_IsValid;
}
```

Here is the snippet from `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit` which creates a list of error messages and shows `alert`:

```
if (summary.showmessagebox == "True") {
    s = "";
    if (typeof(summary.headertext) == "string") {
        s += summary.headertext + "\r\n";
    }
    var lastValIndex = Page_Validators.length - 1;
    for (i=0; i<=lastValIndex; i++) {
        if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid && typeof(Page_Validators[i].errormessage) == "string") {
            switch (summary.displaymode) {
                case "BulletList":
                default:
                    s += "- " + Page_Validators[i].errormessage;
                    if (i < lastValIndex) {
                        s += "\r\n";
                    }
                    break;
                // Other cases omitted to shorten the snippet
            }
        }
    }
    alert(s);
}
```

The only way to make it work consistently is to add client validation function for your custom validator and expose the server side validation function as a web service method.

The first step would be to add `ClientValidationFunction`:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validProductCode" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtProductCode"
    OnServerValidate="ValidateProductCode"
    ClientValidationFunction="validateProductCode"
    ErrorMessage="The product code entered is invalid"
    Display="None" 
    ValidationGroup="IWS"/>
```

Second step is to modify validation method on the server side:

```
protected void ValidateProductCode(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = ValidateProductCode(ddlSiteId.SelectedValue, txtProductCode.Text);
}

// This method would be called both from the client and server side
[WebMethod]
public static bool ValidateProductCode(string siteId, string productCode)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnection.GetConnectionString()))
        using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("PL_ProductCodes_FillScreen", conn))
        {
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", siteId);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", productCode);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsOntext", 1);

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            return ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandling.SQLException(ex, constPageID, constIsSiteSpecific);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Third step is to define client script validation function and call the `ValidateProductCode` method using `JQuery.ajax` call. Please note that I'm not suggesting using `PageMethods` here because in validator function we need to do a "synchronous" call to the server and the simple way is to use JQuery:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validateProductCode(sender, args) {

        var txtProductCodeClientId = "<%= txtProductCode.ClientID %>";
        var productCodeValue = ValidatorGetValue(txtProductCodeClientId);

        var ddlSiteIdClientId = "<%= ddlSiteId.ClientID %>";
        var ddlSiteIdValue = ValidatorGetValue(ddlSiteIdClientId);

        var isValid;
        var parameters = {
            siteId: ddlSiteIdValue,
            productCode: productCodeValue
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/<RELATIVE PATH TO YOUR PAGE>/ValidateProductCode") %>",
            data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                isValid = response.d;
            },
            error: function() {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });

        args.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```

---

Be warned that this approach will make a call to the server whenever `txtProductCode` will change its value and lose focus (i.e. `onchange` event) but this will not automatically update a validation summary so no alert message will be shown. To avoid making such "redundant" calls to server you can clear the `onchange` event handler for `txtProductCode` input after the document been loaded.

---

A quick note if you are using FriendlyUrls:

To make it work you'll need to set `FriendlyUrlSettings.AutoRedirectMode` to `RedirectMode.Off` in your routes configuration.

If that's not an option then you'll need to setup asmx service, see [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: I tried this and I still have the problem with the other validators not showing. I have several validators that are setup on the page load for required fields and regular expressions and I added them into the IWS group also but they are just not working still.

Comment: Also it doesn't hit the code on the product code validate and shows an error no matter what you enter.

Comment: @connersz Then I'm not sure what is happening in your case. Before answering the question I've created a new project and used both `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` with the setup you described. So the code I've posted is verified to be working.

Comment: Its interesting to know what is wrong with this answer so it got a downvote. I like to have a feedback :)

Comment: It didn't solve the problem and it was just the same as before. In the end I had to write a whole new validator control but that still won't show in the same validation summary. I have to make do with a second validation summary box.

Comment: Alright, its up to you. I found a test project I was talking previously: http://1drv.ms/1kIL6vA. What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

In function validateProductCode(sender, args), you can get "productCodeValue"
just by using args.Value:

```
      var productCodeValue = args.Value;
```

You don't need:

```
    var txtProductCodeClientId = "<%= txtProductCode.ClientID %>";
    var productCodeValue = ValidatorGetValue(txtProductCodeClientId);
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify your parameters, use can do this instead:

```
   var parameters = { };
   parameters.siteId = ddlSiteIdValue;
   parameters.productCode = productCodeValue;
```

then in the data argument in your $.ajax({     call, use this:

```
   data:  JSON.stringify(parameters)
```